# How to solve issue related the react-table v6 sticky header issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I'm having an issue with a sticky header. How can I solve that issue? I already tried {position: sticky, top: 0, z-index: 1} but after scrolling down header gt merged with the filter input field.

[image]

Comment: add to header margin-bottom 30px?

Comment: Not working. I tried that too. It's overlapping the filters below the header and I want to scroll both the header and filter blocks.